# Ruby: Circular dependency detected while using Threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

When I run this code, in 9/10 cases Rails raises RuntimeError:
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant SearchEngine

```ruby
def search
  ts_start = Time.now
  results = []
  threads = []
  @engines.each do |name|
    threads << Thread.new do
      engine = "#{name.capitalize}Engine".constantize.new @params, @location
      results << engine.search  
      Thread.exit if results.length == @engines.length || (Time.now - ts_start) > @timeout
    end
  end
  threads.each { |t| t.abort_on_exception = false; t.join }
  unless results.length == 0 then
    # do some stuff...
  end
end
```

However, when I create the new 'engine' instance BEFORE the new thread:

```ruby
engine = "#{name.capitalize}Engine".constantize.new @params, @location    
threads << Thread.new do
  results << engine.search
```

then it runs fine in 9/10 cases. But it still isn't 100%.

When i'm not using threads at all, it runs fine everytime.

Any suggestions how to modify the code?

Comment: Requiring files isn't threadsafe in ruby (including rails' loading on demand). Ensure that everything has been required before threads are started.

Comment: It seems to be fixed, thanks! @FrederickCheung Although the code will require more modifications to be thread-safe.